# PostgreSQL: return row where any column value like variable

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to have the user search for a value in a SQL table, and the user is returned with any row that contains that value. At the moment, I can make it work such that the code is:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE lower('foo') in (lower('col1'),lower('col2'),etc)
```

However, I would like it to be able to search every column and return any row LIKE 'foo'. For instance,

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (lower('col1'), lower('col2'), etc) like lower('%foo%')
```

But that doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use multiple WHERE clauses instead of grouping them all into one statement. Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE lower(col1) like lower('%foo%')
OR lower(col2) like lower('%foo%')
OR etc like lower('%foo%')
```

Comment: I guess you should use `lower(col1) ... lower(coln)` without the quotes, otherwise, you do just literal text to literal text comparison.

Comment: @joanolo Thanks, updated. Of course I'm sure these are just placeholder names for the actual columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the whole row to a string and then use LIKE on the result of that:

```
select *
from the_table
where lower(the_table::text) like '%foo%';
```

`the_table::text` returns all columns of each row as a comma separated list enclosed with parentheses, e.g. `(42,Arthur,Dent)`. So the above is not 100 identical to a LIKE condition applied on each column - but probably does what you want.